# how to make text followed by a rectangle box filled with color html css with responsive

Tags: html, css

I need a small help regarding simple html and css inside a grid.

### like to attach a image which i actually want to achieve

[image]

```css
#rectangle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #8DB23F;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" id="rectangle"><span id="first" style="background-color:white;color:#8DB23F;font-size:40px;padding:7px 0px 2px 1px;border-color:white;margin-left: -15px;"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;JAW CRUSHER&nbsp;</strong></span></div>
</div>
```

I have achieved this as time arround please help me fix this issue (not responsive)

Comment: I suppose you are using bootstrap, and bootstrap allows you to attach a separate class for mobile and other screens. Have you tried using `.col-xs-6`?

Comment: Actually what i want is Heading for a paragraph which is followeded by a rectangle box. in my code i have added padding and backgorund colors to achieve the result, But it is not responsive.

Comment: Tamilall  inaivom thola.. You should try the Pons Purushothaman's answer..

Comment: Thank you have tried and achieved bro

Comment: p.s: i'd suggest not using &nbsp; too much, because it could look much different on other devices like a phone. use css to indent it

Answer (score 2):

This a suggestion and it will work on plane background color and single line text. Just make a try.

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #8DB23F;
}
.row strong{
  line-height: 40px;
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;JAW CRUSHER&nbsp;</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Pons Purushothaman but why am getting border line on top and bottom of the text(JAW crusher) in small devices

Comment: is it in the same green color?? If yes, it may due to line height issues. there may be line height specified in media queries.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#rectangle {
  width: 100%;
  display:block;
  height:40px;
  background-color: red;
}

strong {
  background-color: #fFF;
}
p {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  margin-right:10px;
  font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" style="display:flex;align-items: baseline;">
    <p ><strong> JAW CRUSHER </strong></p>
    <div id="rectangle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help you achieve the required design

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12" id="rectangle"><span id="first"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;JAW CRUSHER&nbsp;</strong></span></div>
</div>
<style>
#rectangle{
     width:100%;
     height:auto;
     background:#8DB23F;
     }
 #first{
 background-color:white;
 color:#8DB23F;
 font-size:40px;
 padding:7px 0px 2px 1px;
 border-color:white;
 margin-left: -15px;
 }
 @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #first {
    font-size:20px;
    }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#Box {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 background: #8DB23F;
}
#name {
 background-color: white;
 color: #8DB23F;
 font-size: 40px;
 padding: 10px 0px 3px 3px;
 border-color: white;
 margin-left: -15px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
#Box {
 height: 100%;
}
#name {
 font-size: 37px;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12" id="Box"><span id="name"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;JAW CRUSHER&nbsp;</strong></span></div>
</div>
```